# How do I classify number values in Python to assign it to a group?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, classification

I have calculated the number of points that exists for a SqMi area and am trying now to assign it to a certain group based on where it falls in the classification. Does anyone know a tool that I can run that will generate an output, or the python code that will help me to test these values to see where they need to be. I have inserted a sample code and I will write some pseudo code so that you can follow my logic to help.

```
#Calculate per sq mi the number of incidents within the zone (Top=15+, High = 12-15, Some = #6-12, Low = >6)
# Get the shape_area number from the CurrentZoneLayer
field = "SHAPE_Area"
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("CurrentZoneLayer",field)as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        zoneSqMi = (row[0]/2589988.11)
        print "Zone SqMi: "+ str(zoneSqMi)

# Divide the zoneSqMi by the number selected to get points by SqMi
pointsPerSqMi = numSelected/zoneSqMi
print "Points Per Sq Mi: " + str(pointsPerSqMi)

# Create a series of tests to see which group the points will fall under Top, High,  #Some, Low
# if pointsPerSqMi > 15 then print "Top"
# if pointsPerSqMi <15 and pointsPerSqMi
```

Eventually these categories will be written into a field value as well, but for now I am just trying to figure out the logic on how to assign it to a group within a script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic grouping logic can be handled with [if/elif statements](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html) and [interval comparison](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons). For example:

```
if pointsPerSqMi >= 15:
    print "Top"
elif 15 > pointsPerSqMi >= 12:
    print "High"
elif 12 > pointsPerSqMi >= 6:
    print "Some"
else:
    print "Low"
```

Replace the `print` with updating a field once you're satisfied with the logic.

EDIT: You should be able to use an [Update Cursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000014000000) (instead of the Search Cursor used earlier, which just reads data, an Update Cursor lets you modify data), something like:

```
fields = ("SHAPE_Area", "Category")
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("CurrentZoneLayer",fields) as cursor:
    for row in corsor:
        zoneSqMi = (row[0]/2589988.11)
        pointsPerSqMi = numSelected/zoneSqMi
        if pointsPerSqMi >= 15:
            row[1] = "Top"
        elif 15 > pointsPerSqMi >= 12:
            row[1] = "High"
        elif 12 > pointsPerSqMi >= 6:
            row[1] = "Some"
        else:
            row[1] = "Low"
```

I haven't tried running this, so it may need debugging. (Also, you may want to store the calculated square mileage of the zone in an additional third field, but that's optional.)

Comment: Thank you Erica! That worked. What do I need to insert in order to update the field?

Comment: Added that detail in. Please "accept" the answer (checkmark below the upvote/downvote arrows) if it does indeed work for you :)

Comment: Thank you so much! Can't give you an upvote as I am a newbie and don't have enough reputation yet :) Thanks again!!